# What i am missing in my js code i am getting missing ) error

Tags: javascript, html

What am I missing in my code?  I am getting following error in the developer console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Full code here:

```
    .html('<textarea id="textarea" rows="1" class="form-control chatboxtextarea" data-autosize-on="true" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; height: 30px;" 
onkeypress="javascript:return updateLastTypedTime();" onkeyup="javascript:return refreshTypingStatus(' + chatboxtitle + "','" + toid + "');\" 
onkeydown=\"javascript:return checkChatBoxInputKey(event,this,'" + chatboxtitle + "','" + toid + "','" + img + '\');">
</textarea>');
```

I think i am missing something this line:

```
onkeypress="javascript:return updateLastTypedTime();" onkeyup="javascript:return refreshTypingStatus(' + chatboxtitle + "','" + toid + "');\"
```

but where I really can not fined :/

Comment: that doesn't seem to be your `Full code`

Comment: unlike URIs, event handler don't need the `javascript` pseudo-protocol.

Comment: @LucaKiebel I just share error line here. No need to share all code here.

Comment: You probably have a unescaped quote somewhere

Comment: @TaylorAckley Yes you are exactly right but where. I think I am missing something this line: `onkeypress="javascript:return updateLastTypedTime();" onkeyup="javascript:return refreshTypingStatus(' + chatboxtitle + "','" + toid + "');\"`

Comment: Looks like you are reversing the order of the double and single quotes when you interpolate the variables.

Comment: Read up on the DOM API. It’ll be much easier than piecing HTML together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.html(
    '<textarea id="textarea" rows="1" class="form-control chatboxtextarea" data-autosize-on="true" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; height: 30px;"
    onkeypress="javascript:return updateLastTypedTime();"
    onkeyup="javascript:return refreshTypingStatus(' + chatboxtitle + "','" + toid + "');\" 
    onkeydown=\"javascript:return checkChatBoxInputKey(event,this,'" + chatboxtitle + "','" + toid + "','" + img + '\');">
```

Those quotes are a mess. The problem lies right here:

```
'...refreshTypingStatus(' + chatboxtitle + "','" + toid + "')
```

```
^                       ^                  ^
|                       |                  |
|                       Your closing       Your opening quote for
Your opening quote      quote for the      another string literal.
for the string          string literal     These are suddenly
literal                                    double quotes. Bad.
                                           Don't mix up quotes.
```

So when the HTML is inserted by the `html()` function, your `refreshTypingStatus()` function becomes this:

```
refreshTypingStatus(Nice title','My very own toid')
```

As you can see, the title doesn't start with quotes. You'll need to simply insert the quote:

```
'...refreshTypingStatus(\'' + chatboxtitle + "','" + toid + "')..."
```